# View logic inside fxml (iterating in particular)

Tags: java, loops, collections, javafx, fxml

So, here's an example fxml from yfiles developer's guide (not that important actually):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import com.yworks.yfiles.drawing.NodeTemplate?>

<NodeTemplate fx:id="templateNode" style="-fx-background-color: darkblue"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
    <VBox alignment="CENTER">
        <Label fx:id="firstName" text="${templateNode.item.tag.firstName}"
            textFill="${templateNode.styleTag.firstNameColor}" />

        <Label fx:id="lastName" text="${templateNode.item.tag.lastName}"
            textFill="${templateNode.styleTag.lastNameColor}" />
    </VBox>
</NodeTemplate>
```

templateNode.item.tag is an object of Person class:

```
public class Person {

    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    public Person(String firstName, String lastName){
        this.firstName = firstName; this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {return firstName;}
    public String getLastName() {return lastName;}
}
```

Is it possible **inside fxml** to:

a) perform some view-logic (that's how i call it) inside fxml?
For example to make first label's text to be set to templateNode.item.tag.firstName if and only if it's length is > 10 and "whatever" otherwise?

b) at least specifically iterate over a collection from model?
Imagine templateNode.item.tag is a **list** of Person objects.
For example in pydjanvaFX (which is django-enhanced-templating inside javaFX, language i invented on the occasion of writing this question) language i can write something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import com.yworks.yfiles.drawing.NodeTemplate?>

<NodeTemplate fx:id="templateNode" style="-fx-background-color: darkblue"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
    <VBox alignment="CENTER">
        {% for i, model in enumerate(templateNode.item.tag) %}
            <Label fx:id="firstName#${i}" text="${model.firstName}"
                textFill="${templateNode.styleTag.firstNameColor}" />

            <Label fx:id="lastName#${i}" text="${model.lastName}"
                textFill="${templateNode.styleTag.lastNameColor}" />
        {% endfor %}
    </VBox>
</NodeTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read [Introduction to FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) and about [Scripting in FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#scripting).

> The `<fx:script>` tag allows a caller to import scripting code into or
>   embed script within a FXML file. Any JVM scripting language can be
>   used, including JavaScript, Groovy, and Clojure, among others. Script
>   code is often used to define event handlers directly in markup or in
>   an associated source file, since event handlers can often be written
>   more concisely in more loosely-typed scripting languages than they can
>   in a statically-typed language such as Java.

*However, I strongly advise against it. You want to find compile time errors, not runtime errors.*

A brief example about how a script could look like, a label is added dynamically:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?language javascript?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>


<VBox fx:id="root" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
    <children>
        <Button text="Button" />
        <Label text="Label" />
    </children>
    <fx:define>
        <Label fx:id="addedLabel" text="Label" />
    </fx:define>
    <fx:script>
        addedLabel.setText('Added Label');
        root.getChildren().add( addedLabel);
        java.lang.System.out.println( "Children: " + root.getChildren().size());
    </fx:script>
</VBox>
```

I won't go any deeper into this or lists or whatever scripting you want to do, because seriously: don't do it this way! Sooner or later you'll run into problems.

Comment: Well it's sad, since most tutorials actually favor declaring view in fxml over java (and as much as i hate anything xml-ish i can actually understand it in this particular case) and now i'm told it's only useful for the most basic stuff.

Comment: Yes, "view". But what you are doing is putting code into it. That's something totally different ;-)

Comment: Web frameworks got me used to something totally different, although django still forces me to declare date format in separate file :v

Comment: And code responsible for view and view only still belongs to view, imo.